# Problem with Execute immedite

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to run this code below using Execute Immediate but its not working and     values are correct.

Please suggest the correct code.

```
declare
v_count number:=1;
v_conc_name varchar2(400);
v_val VARCHAR2(20):='vineet';
BEGIN 
v_conc_name:='INT_AP_PAY_CONV';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE xxx_cnc_prg_details
               SET
               PARAMETER'||v_count||'='
               ||v_val||' where CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME= '||v_conc_name;

end;
```

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Answer (score 5):

It's a lot easier (and better practice) to use bind variables:

```
declare
v_count number:=1;
v_conc_name varchar2(400);
v_val VARCHAR2(20):='vineet';
BEGIN 
v_conc_name:='INT_AP_PAY_CONV';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE xxx_cnc_prg_details
               SET
               PARAMETER'||v_count||'=:bv_val
               where CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME=:bv_conc_name'
  USING v_val, v_conc_name;

end;
```

It's also a handy practice to use a string variable to hold the SQL.  Then you can use DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE to view and verify it:

```
declare
v_count number:=1;
v_conc_name varchar2(400);
v_val VARCHAR2(20):='vineet';
v_sql LONG;
BEGIN 
v_conc_name:='INT_AP_PAY_CONV';
v_sql := 'UPDATE xxx_cnc_prg_details
               SET
               PARAMETER'||v_count||'=:bv_val
               where CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME=:bv_conc_name';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING v_val, v_conc_name;

end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems you missed quotes:

should be:

```
 ||' where CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME= '''||v_conc_name || '''';
```

because v_conc_name is varchar2

Comment: @OmerGertel, I believe the missing space after PARAMETER is correct, i.e. the code is generating the column name PARAMETER1.

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
DECLARE
  c           CONSTANT CHAR := '''';
  v_conc_name VARCHAR2(400) := 'INT_AP_PAY_CONV';
  v_val       VARCHAR2(20)  := 'vineet';
  v_count     NUMBER        := 1;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE xxx_cnc_prg_details
                     SET
                     PARAMETER'||v_count||' = '||c||v_val||c||'
                     where CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_SHORT_NAME = '||c||v_conc_name||c;

END;
```

Comment: I prefer concatenation if dynamic part is long (what it's not in this case), because with bind variables maintaining of code is little bit harder. And I'm doing lot's of Forms code where I'm needing quote char concatenation more often.